# Bootstrap progressbar text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Problem: Bootstrap progress bar text will only show text if there is any progress made.

[image]

What I tried: Putting it in different places, just after the div will mess up the CSS and in the main
progress div too.

Optimal solution: This is how I want it to look:

[image]

So the text will show no matter how much progress there is. Should be an easy solution but I just can't figure it out.

This is where the progress-bar text is currently at.

```
   echo'
          <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90"
                   aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:'.$width.'%">'
  ?>
                 <div class="innerProgress"> € <?php echo $singleRow["opgehaald"]; echo "&nbsp";>
opgehaald </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just the text blending into the background when there's little progress? If that's the case it's just a matter of darkening the non-progress part of the bar.

Comment: I've tried that sorry i dind't mention it. It dissapears so colors don't matter.

Comment: You might did not see it but you are having a php error as it is not closed: `<?php echo $singleRow["opgehaald"]; echo "&nbsp";>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap hides the `overflow` thus the text looks truncated. setting width and overflow property on the `.innerProgress` class should help you get the desired result. you can adjust the background color and text color to make it the way you have shown in OP.

```css
.innerProgress {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:20%">
    <div class="innerProgress"> € opgehaald this is very long text and must be shown and its goes very long</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:2%">
    <div class="innerProgress"> this one has only 2% progress</div>
  </div>
</div>
```